# Using the hyperlinks in asp.net Calendar

Tags: asp.net, mysql, calendar

I have a asp.net calendar that I'm using as a time tracker. Currently, I have a mysql query populating the calendar with the required info but I don't know how to retrieve this info when one of the days is selected. When a user selects the date, I want to take the information from the date and populate a couple labels. Calendar code is below. Thanks.

```
        If Not dsDate Is Nothing Then
        For Each dr As DataRow In dsDate.Tables(0).Rows
            description = CType(dr("Description"), String)
            nextDate = CType(dr("Date"), DateTime)
            hours = CType(dr("Hours"), Integer)
            If nextDate = e.Day.Date And description = "Sick" Then
                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen
                e.Cell.ToolTip = description & " - " & hours & " Hours"
            ElseIf nextDate = e.Day.Date And description = "Vacation" Then
                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Brown
                e.Cell.ToolTip = description & " - " & hours & " Hours"
            End If
        Next
    End If
    If e.Day.IsWeekend Then
        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSkyBlue
        e.Day.IsSelectable = False
    End If
    If nottouched And Not e.Day.IsWeekend And Not e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen And Not e.Day.IsOtherMonth And Not e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Brown Then
        e.Cell.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", onmouseoverStyle)
        e.Cell.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", onmouseoutStyle.Replace("@BackColor", rowBackColor))
    End If
```

Comment: What do u exactly mean by 'take the information from the date', do u want the selected date itself?

Comment: I want the selected date and the info that I've added into the tooltip of that date to be added to a couple labels on the page. Or if it is easier, when a date is clicked, I want to run a query against mysql to populate the labels. 

Basically, I don't know what is happening when a date gets clicked! I'm new to this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The following code populates the label with the date selected in C#:

> monthCalendar1.MaxSelectionCount = 1;
>   label1.Text = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();

Now you can run a query based on this date and try to get other values.

Comment: I jumped the gun on this one. I don't have any choices for maxselectioncount or selectionrange. 

I believe I'm on the right track with:

selecteddate = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString()
query = "Select Date, Description, Hours from Vacation Where login='username' and Where Date='" & selecteddate & "'"

Problem with this is that I'm doing this in the dayrender event so selecteddate goes through every day of the month when the calendar loads.